# Python error when executing shell script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I'm executing a line of shell script using python. It isn't working with `which` to test of the existence of homebrew

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, subprocess
subprocess.call(["which python"])
```

throws the long error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "installations.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["which python"]) 
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But I know that the shell execution is working correctly on some level

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, subprocess
subprocess.call(["whoami])
```

prints my username just fine. Am I doing something wrong, or is which for some reason not supported. Is there some better supported way of detecting the existence of an installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failing call is trying to find an executable named 'which python' not running `which` with an argument of `python` as you likely intended.  The list that you pass to call (unless `shell=True` is set) is the list of the command and all the arguments.  Doing

```
subprocess.call(['which', 'python'])
```

will probably give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect. So is there something better for executing strings of shell script? Something like PHP's `shell_exec()`? Thanks so much!

Comment: The `subprocess` module is the "best" way to execute commands from python generally.  If you want it to look more like a shell command as you'd type it, and probably is more like PHP's `shell_exec` you can add the argument `shell=True` to your `call()` function, then the first argument becomes a string to exec at a shell instead of the executable and argument list as a lilst, so you could do `subprocess.call( "which python", shell=True)` for this example if you wanted to--but then you have to deal with lots more quote escaping and stuff like that

Answer (score 3):

When calling this way you need to separate each word on your command line as a different element of an iterable:

```
subprocess.call(["which", "python"])
```

I *highly* recommend reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) several times through in order to truly understand all the possible ways of launching subprocesses and how they differ from each other.